# Проблема с git clone

Tags: git

при клонировании репозитория выдает ошибку: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502,

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать SSH вместо HTTP, должно помочь

[Источник](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-clone-failure-error-RPC-failed-result-22-HTTP-code-504/qaq-p/297320)

Comment: а в чем проблема почему мне нужно использовать именно ssh?

Comment: @vasypu об этом вы можете прочитать тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041729/why-does-github-recommend-https-over-ssh

Comment: @vasypu да и вообще с ssh намного проще работать и с ним возникает меньше проблем. Вам помог ответ?

Comment: пока не могу сказать, мне теперь надо разобраться как задействовать ssh и смотреть что получится с моей ошибкой